# MUI TextField - Input Label Color On Hover

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I currently have a `CustomTextField` styled Mui TextField that will change the input background color and font color when hovered over. However, I also want to change the label font color on hover. Currently, the input background changes from black to white on hover and the font color does the opposite. I want the label color to also change from white to black on hover.

How can I achieve this? I have tried adding an OnMouseOver and OnMouseLeave event listener and manually setting the label color, but adding the OnMouseOver listener seems to break the TextField completely. This is my code:

[codesandbox.io/s/brave-dew-d472zl?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-dew-d472zl?file=/src/App.js)

```
const CustomTextField = styled((props) => (
    <TextField
      InputLabelProps={{
        // getTextColor() checks a state variable called hoveredControl which just stores
        // the id of the currently hovered component. If the hoveredControl is this input,
        // set the text color to black otherwise, set to white.
        sx: { color: getTextColor(props.id) },
      }}
      InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}
      {...props}
    />
  ))(({ theme }) => ({
    "& .MuiFilledInput-root": {
      overflow: "hidden",
      borderRadius: 4,
      backgroundColor: "#232323",
      color: "#FFFFFF",
      border: "1px solid",
      borderColor: "#2D3843",
      transition: theme.transitions.create(["border-color", "background-color", "box-shadow"]),
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "#bdbdbd",
        color: "#000000",
      },
      "&.Mui-focused": {
        color: "#000000",
        backgroundColor: "#bdbdbd",
        boxShadow: `${alpha(theme.palette.primary.main, 0.25)} 0 0 0 2px`,
        borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
      },
    },
}));
```

Comment: Can you provide a small replicable example on https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: @mandy8055 https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-dew-d472zl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thanks. Does **[this](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-babbage-3whcmc?file=/src/App.js)** help?

Comment: @mandy8055 if you type inside the TextField and then move your mouse somewhere else, the text just gets reset. I would also prefer not having to store the TextField value in state as I plan on having a lot of inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix this by using the following CSS properties on the styled TextField component:

```
"& label.Mui-focused": {
  color: "#000000" // Change label color when input is focused
},
"&:hover label": {
  color: "#000000" // Change label color when input is hovered
}
```

No need to store anything in state or do anything fancy with mouseOver/mouseEnter listeners.

Link to solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-dew-d472zl?file=/src/Fixed.js